# Get PHP's imagefttext() to show Chinese characters

Tags: php, image, character-encoding

I am trying to get `imagefttext()` to display Chinese characters, but it just displays square boxes

Here is some simplified code to show the problem

```
<?php
// Create a 300x100 image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

// Make the background red
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 299, 99, $red);

// Path to our ttf font file
$font_file = 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf';

// Draw the text '牧師' using font size 13
imagefttext($im, 13, 0, 105, 55, $black, $font_file, '牧師');

// Output image to the browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This is what it produces:

[image]

Is it to do with the font, or some other character set setting in PHP?

I've tried various fonts, but I just can't seem to get the

> 牧師

characters to display

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get them to show up by using the SimSun font

Replacing

`$font_file = 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf';`

With

`$font_file = 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simsun.ttc';`

Makes it work

Answer (score 0):

[Please download font at your font folder and try because i have already done this text at my local server]

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/SimSun/
[image]